# Swift Charts- Bar Chart Vertical Grid Lines

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I am currently using [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and can not figure out a way to get rid of these vertical grid lines. Here is some of the code I have that gets what the picture has.

```
for i in 0..<totalExpense.count {
            if totalExpense[i].total != 0 {
                dataEntries.append(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: totalExpense[i].total))
                colors.append(randomColor(hue: .random, luminosity: .light))
            }
            else {
                emptyCount += 1
            }
        }

        //Add all the chart data
        if emptyCount != 12 {
            let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "")
            let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
            chartDataSet.colors = colors

            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .currency
            chartData.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: formatter))

            barChart.data = chartData
            barChart.data?.setValueTextColor(.black)

            barChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: months)
            barChart.xAxis.granularity = 1
            barChart.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
            barChart.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
            barChart.xAxis.labelCount = 12

            barChart.rightAxis.gridColor = .clear

            barChart.leftAxis.enabled = false
            barChart.rightAxis.enabled = false

            barChart.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
            barChart.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
            barChart.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false

            barChart.legend.enabled = false
```

[image: Bar Chart]

Comment: try adding `barChart.xAxis.gridColor = .clear` and `barChart.xAxis.gridColor = .clear`

Comment: @MayRestinPeace Those grids aren't xAxis I thought? But it worked! So thank you very much

Comment: If it worked, I'll add it as answer so people who stumble upon it, get help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this [comment](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/579#issuecomment-451481274) in the library's github repo add these two lines:

`barChart.xAxis.gridColor = .clear`

`barChart.yAxis.gridColor = .clear`

This is just a workaround but apparently the only solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

above answer is a way-out, but you can play with enable property of grid line with just one line code

Here is Code

```
barChart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
```